# Pass SharedPreferences to List widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a flutter application with a navigation bar and I need to pass some variables to my List widget. The problem is that the List widget is built before my variable is initialized so I can't use it.

I already tried to use "super.initState();" and things like that but the only thing I got (as best result) was an empty variable.

Here is my List widget which is used for my bottom navigation bar:

```dart
** Some code**

SharedPreferences prefs;

List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    TabScreen(currentUserId: prefs.getString("id")),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School var',
    ),
    Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(

        ),
      ),
    ),
  ];
```

With this code I have a message "Only satic members can be accessed in initializers" on the line "TabScreen(currentUserId: prefs.getString("id"))" which is logical as my List is initialized before I can access "prefs" variable but I can't manage to solve the problem.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to build it in didChangeDependencies? Most of the times this works for me. Until then i give the widget a placeholder Container. (or for fancy reasons a SpinKitDualRing)

Comment: You mean to put the whole "List" widget in didChangeDependencies() ? If I'm putting the "List" widget into didChangeDependencies() the problem is that I can't access the "_widgetOptions" variable in my "Widget build"

Answer (score 0):

```
String id;

Future<Null> getSharedPrefs() async           

{

SharedPreferences prefs = await  
      SharedPreferences. getInstance() ;

id = prefs. getString("id" );

}

initState () {
super. initState () ;
id="" ;
getSharedPrefs() ;
}
```

Now you can use this id in list..

Comment: You mean like that? https://pastebin.com/zpj02WnE If yes, I still get the "Only satic members can be accessed in initializers" on the "id" variable in my list. Thanks

Comment: Then try with initializing Id null.. Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your time but unfortunately, still the same problem

Comment: Then, pass this id as parameter when you calling this bottom navigation..

Answer (score 0):

```
 String _id;
 SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getSharedPrefs();
  }

  getSharedPrefs() async{

    _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _id = _sharedPreferences.getString("id");
    setState(() {

    });
  }
```

This may help you

Comment: You mean like that? https://pastebin.com/zpj02WnE If yes, I still get the "Only satic members can be accessed in initializers" on the "id" variable in my list. Thanks